# Accesspoints multiple VLANs

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

I am really new to this VLANs and have watched and read some tutorials and how-tos, but i can't get my setup to work. 
I have the following situation:

- 4 Accesspoints with 2 SSIDs (work and public)
- 2 Switches (one for the APs and one for the internal LAN)
- 1 CISCO ASA (Firewall that is connected to our internet service provider)

How do I have to tag the VLAN ports on both switches that my setup is working?
I made a (not so beautiful) ASCII graphic from my setup:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally speaking, a VLAN capable wifi Access Point is a switch. So you treat the link between the HP swicth and the APs the same way as between 2 switches. I.E. trunk ports.

*Note that here I use the term "trunk" for a port on which several tagged VLAN are allowed. In HP terminology "trunk" refers to link aggregation, which has nothing to do with VLANs.*

Since you didn't provide VLAN number, I'll give some example with arbitrary numbers.

Let's use :

- VLAN2 : used for APs and switches management
- VLAN3 : work VLAN used for both "work" wifi SSID and internal LAN
- VLAN4 : "public" wifi SSID

You need to configure your ports as

> **ASA**
>
> - port connected to the HP Switch1 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3 and 4
>
> **Switch1**
>
> - port 17 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3 and 4
> - ports 1,2,3 & 4 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3 and 4;  and native VLAN 2 (depending on you AP model, but suitable for most AP)
> - port 24 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2 and 3
>
> **Switch2**
>
> - port connected to switch1 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2 and 3

If you want to separate the "work" wifi from the internal LAN, we add VLAN5 for Internal LAN and this give us:

> **ASA**
>
> - port connected to the HP Switch1 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3,4 and 5
>
> **Switch1**
>
> - port 17 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3,4 and 5
> - ports 1,2,3 & 4 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2,3 and 4;  and native VLAN 2 (depending on you AP model, but suitable for most AP)
> - port 24 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2 and 5
>
> **Switch2**
>
> - port connected to switch1 : trunk with allowed VLAN 2 and 5

P.S. nice ascii drawing.

Comment: Thank you, @JFL for your answer. What does "allowed" mean? I have the options "tagged, untagged, forbid, no" for each port.

Comment: On some switches when configuring a "trunk" port (with multiple tagged vlan) you can choose which one are allowed (thus preventing frame belonging to other VLANs to pass trough). But this is very dependent of the vendor and switch model. I'm not used to HP procurve so cannot detail on this, but setting the need VLANs as tagged on the port should do it.

Comment: Note that for the AP management "native vlan" means untagged. Some AP models can be managed trough a tagged vlan, but some others can only be managed from the native (untagged) VLAN.

Comment: I will keep that in mind :)